# Noun describing movement through an area

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a noun that describes a single movement through a pre-defined area. Up until now I've been able to use **pass**, as in "the person made a single pass through the room," but on its own I feel that "pass" is not descriptive enough, and "pass through" gets too long/awkward.

For context, this will be used to name a construct within a program, where a `RoomPass` would be an object describing one person's movement through a `Room`.

Comment: *Cross* the room?

Comment: **Cross** is close, but I should have specified that the person may not always start at one side and end at the opposite. Imagine a hallway: a person may move from one connected room to another, but those rooms could both be on the same side. In that case I wouldn't say the person _crossed_ the hallway, but they still _passed through_ it.

Comment: That's about whatever language you're programming in, not English. If it was about English, how could you distinguish "move" or "pass" or "move/pass through"? Either way, please note *they* can't apply to one person and however many people, they passed "along", not "through" anything (exceptions apply). What's ambiguous in English won't become *more* clear in a less-forgiving language.

Comment: A record of a single path is often called a trajectory. Trace is also a good option. A trajectory would tend to suggest rate info, hence time coordinates in addition to spacial coordinates.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because naming software variables is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

#### passage

> an act of moving through an area
>
> *Despite security checks, our passage through the airport was fairly quick.*

([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/passage))

This has the advantage of always being a noun, where "pass" is sometimes a verb.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a short descriptive word, the word you've used fits

> **move** *verb*
>   \ˈmüv  \
>   moved; moving
>   <sup>https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moved</sup>

Or you could go with a more interesting word

> **traverse** *verb*
>   tra·​verse | \trə-ˈvərs also tra-ˈvərs or ˈtra-(ˌ)vərs  \
>   traversed; traversing
>   Definition of traverse (Entry 1 of 3)
>   *transitive verb*
>   1a : to go or travel across or over
>   b : to move or pass along or through
>   <sup>https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/traverse</sup>

With your example sentence (fragment):

> the person **moved through** the room
>   the person **traversed** the room

Your object could be named `RoomPath` or `RoomTraversal`, describing the path that something took rather than the action (even in programming, objects prefer to define objects).

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to borrow a term from the telephone industry, which has often found a need for abstract terms when ordinary concrete common-sense terms could be misleading.

For example, on a multi-line phone unit connected to a switchboard, there is the concept of a *line appearance*. The switchboard is connected to several outside lines, of which a subset can “appear” on any given phone unit. It’s mostly a historical term these days, but you can find it in old manuals like [this one from Mitel](http://edocs.mitel.com/UG/EN/2ICP_4025_UG_R2_EN.pdf).

So you could have a **RoomAppearance**, defined (like a phone call) by its start time, end time and the equivalent of a calling party.